# Refer multiple Resource Dictionaries in the UWP project

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, resourcedictionary, resx

My UWP app has a resource dictionary used for localization named "Resources.resx" and now I want to add another "ResourcesXaml.resx". I want to know how to access both files like merged.

[image]

The code is below. I want to use the same `Get(string key)` method and access any resource in both files. Appreciate it if anyone can point out the change I need to make. Cheers!

```
static ResourceHandler()
    {
        const string selectedLanguage = "en";
        Context = ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();

        var lang = new List<string> { selectedLanguage };
        Context.Languages = lang;
        ResourceStringMap = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("Resources");
    }

    public static string Get(string key)
    {
        return ResourceStringMap.GetValue(key, Context).ValueAsString;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create two `ResourceMaps` and look up the key in the second one if the lookup in the first one fails, e.g.:

```
public static class ResourceHandler
{
    private const string SelectedLanguage = "en";
    private static readonly ResourceContext s_resourceContext = 
        new ResourceContext() { Languages = new string[1] { SelectedLanguage } };
    private static readonly ResourceMap s_resourcesMap =
        ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("Resources");
    private static readonly ResourceMap s_resourcesXamlMap =
        ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("ResourcesXaml");

    public static string Get(string key)
    {
        string s = s_resourcesMap.GetValue(key, s_resourceContext).ValueAsString;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return s;

        return s_resourcesXamlMap.GetValue(key, s_resourceContext).ValueAsString;
    }
}
```